# setTimeout() not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I've got this simple function which displays a message to the user. If I add the timeout parameter it will slide back up automatically if not the user has to click it to get rid. But the timeout bit isn't working.

```
function feedback(text, timeout){
    $('#feedback').text(text).slideDown('fast');

    $('#feedback').click(function(){
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
    if(timeout){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#feedback').slideup();
        }, timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you passed as timeout argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$('#feedback').slideup();` needs a capital `U` in there (e.g. [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)).  You can also shorten it down a bit overall doing this:

```
function feedback(text, timeout){
    var fb = $('#feedback').text(text).slideDown('fast');
    if(timeout) fb.delay(timeout).slideUp();

    fb.click(function(){
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
}
```

This uses the built-in [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) functionality of jQuery to achieve the same effect in a more concise way.

Answer (score -3):

putting a whole function call inside a set timeout function is not valid. Your setTimeout will never trigger as you might want it to, as setTimeout will only accept a function reference.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#feedback').slideup();
}, timeout);
```

Try the following code:

```
var ref = function() {
  $('#feedback').slideup();
};
setTimeout(ref, timeout);
```

Comment: This is incorrect as well, passing an entire function is perfectly valid.  See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/XaEYx/

Comment: Wrong. It is perfectly acceptable to pass an entire function construct as a parameter. It's called a `closure`